# what does max(max(L)) in MATLAB means?

Tags: matlab

what does following code in MATLAB means?

```
L = bwlabel(B,8)
mx= max(max(L))
```

any ideas?

Comment: see, I am a newbie, if I had to read it on wikipedia I would never have come here. so please do not discourage me or any other newbie by down-voting or by even providing url of external sites.

Comment: @twesh: providing urls to the online documentation of Matlab is actually helpful. Still, I don't see any reason for downvoting this question, so +1 to counteract that.

Comment: @twesh: you should not read wikipedia but MATLAB documentation. It is very well written and has many examples. All newbie questions can be answered simply looking for the corresponding function in the MATLAB documentation.

Comment: @Mikhail: What you say is true for someone with experience with Matlab. Even though the documentation is really good, it still does take a bit till you understand it if you're a newbie. However, together with an explanation on SO, the help should become sufficiently easy to understand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`max` takes, by default, the maximum of an array along the first non-singleton dimension. If `L` is a 2D array (which it should, given your call to `bwlabel`), the first call of `max` collapses the first dimension, so that there is only one row with column maxima, and the second call collapses the second dimension, so that there is only a scalar maximum left. In this example, `max(max(L))` is equivalent to `max(L(:))`

Since `bwlabel` performs connected component labeling (i.e. labeling each connected group of pixels with unique, sequential integers), `mx` tells you the number of groups of pixels in the image.

**EDIT**

As @gnovice mentions in the comments, the highest label assigned by `bwlabel` is returned as its second output argument: `[L,mx] = bwlabel(B,8);`

Comment: It should also be noted that the computation of mx is not necessary in this example. You can easily get the number of connected components by getting the second output from BWLABEL, like so: [L,mx]=bwlabel(B,8);

Answer (score 4):

[`bwlabel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/bwlabel.html) returns a 2D matrix of connected components.  Nested `max()` like that returns the single largest value in a 2D matrix, so, the highest component found.